# How to resolve a Promise after all async calls inside a Readable Events are awaited?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, events, promise

Right now I am trying to read file with lots of lines, and I need to insert each of the line into the database in a stream manner. Is this possible?

This is what I have currently,

```
async function insertToDb(data) {
    await repository.save(new Entity("id", "name", "address"));
}

return new Promise((resolve) => {
    Readable.from(buffer)
    .on('data', async (data) => await insertToDb(data))
    .on('end', () => {
        resolve(1);
    });
});
```

So the code above did read all the lines in the file, but the asynchronous database operations were executed AFTER the `Promise.resolve(1)`. How to ensure that all database operations have finished before I resolve the promise?

Comment: add all `this.insertToDb(data)` to an array, then use Promise.all to await them

Comment: is it OK that each `insertToDb(data)` doesn't wait for the previous one to finish - like what happens in your code?

Answer (score 2):

The Promise returned by the data handler is going unused. You'll need to use them all somehow - such as by pushing to an array outside the callback, then using `Promise.all` inside the `end` handler.

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const dbPromises = [];
    Readable.from(buffer)
      .on('data', (data) => {
        dbPromises.push(insertToDb(data));
       })
      .on('end', () => {
        Promise.all(dbPromises).then(() => resolve(1));
      });
});
```

You also might consider adding an error handler that rejects the Promise, so that the caller can see that something went wrong if something does go wrong.

Comment: I have been thinking about using `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled`, but I think both of these methods would violate the Stream approach (since it has started to use an array). Am I out of options? :(

Comment: The stream's native approach with asynchronous `data` callbacks just isn't compatible by default with your desire for a Promise-based approach - so you need to construct the logic needed yourself. I don't see how this is limiting your options, really, you just need to reshape your code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST wait for the stream to end before calling `resolve()`, but don't want to store all the promises into an array for `Promise.all` and break the purpose of streams, there's two ways I would go about it.

### Method 1 (efficient but risky)

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let dbPromise;

    Readable.from(buffer)
      .on('data', (data) => {
        dbPromise = insertToDb(data);
       })
      .on('end', () => {
        dbPromise.then(() => resolve(1));
      });
});
```

This keeps continously updating `dbPromise` up until the last line of the file. After which, `on('end')` is called and awaits `dbPromise` (which will be the last line in the file).

But this comes with a risk. Let's suppose, for whatever reason, the last HTTP request finishes before the second-to-last request (this happened to me many times). The function would've already been resolved by the time the last request finishes. Now, this may or may not be something worth worrying about (depending on your case), but the risk is there.

### Method 2 (not as performant)

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let unfinishedPromises = [];

    Readable.from(buffer)
      .on('data', (data) => {
        const dbPromise = insertToDb(data);
        unfinishedPromises.push(dbPromise);
        dbPromise.then(() => {
            // Remove dbPromise from unfinishedPromises when dbPromise completes.
            unfinishedPromises.splice(unfinishedPromises.indexOf(dbPromise), 1);
        });
       })
      .on('end', () => {
        Promise.all(unfinishedPromises).then(() => resolve(1));
      });
});
```

Pretty self-explanatory. Promises are added to `unfinishedPromises`, and if they complete before `on('end')` is called, they're removed from the array. When `on('end')` finally runs, it `Promise.all` any remaining unfinishedPromises.

This elimantes the risk in Method #1, but the "Stream approach" would be broken. This is countered however in that size of unfinishedPromises would be kept at a minimum.

Hope this helps you :). Stay coding.